# Looping through a segment of a video file using VLCJ

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I've spent a massive amount of time on this, but just can't crack it.

Basically, I need to loop through a **segment** of a video file (like a minute or so over and over again) using vlcj library.

On the first iteration the selected segment (from 100's second of the file) is being played just fine, but then it just plays from the very beginning of the video file, which is not what I need of course

```
Media media = new SimpleMedia("C://video.avi", ":start-time=100", ":stop-time=200");
mediaPlayer.playMedia(media);
mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true);
```

How can this be achieved with vlcj?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in vlcj, the auto-repeat functionality is not honouring the previously set media options.

This has now been fixed in vlcj and will be included in version 3.11.0 when it is released.

What may work in the meantime is to use "standard" media options:

```
mediaPlayer.setStandardMediaOptions(":start-time=100", ":stop-time=200");
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This really saved the day. The woraround worked indeed.
I will be looking for the release of v.3.11.0. Is there a link where updates on the releases is being posted?

Comment: I won't post a link in case it's considered poor form, but search for caprica twitter, that's where releases are posted.